# How to apply condition in ng-hide and ng-show - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am making an angularjs app and in this I want to minimize and maximize a box.

Now I want to hide one div on click and open another div

```
             <div class="msg" ng-hide="msg_div">
                    <a ng-click="msg_div = true"></a>
                some content
            </div>

             <div class="body" ng-show="body_div">
                  <a ng-click="body_div = true"></a>
              </div>
```

Now I want to show second div on hide first div, similarly vice-versa(showing first div on hiding 2nd div).

Any kind of help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

So you pretty much have one boolean that you toggle. One div hides if it's true and the other one hides if it's false.

And also, it's always better to try and do any sort of logic within the controller.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('PageController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showTopPanel = true;

  $scope.togglePanels = function() {
    $scope.showTopPanel = !$scope.showTopPanel;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PageController">
  <div class="msg" ng-show="showTopPanel">
    <a ng-click="togglePanels()"><b>click to toggle</b></a>
    <div>
      top panel
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="body" ng-hide="showTopPanel">
    <a ng-click="togglePanels()"><b>click totoggle</b></a>
    <div>
      bottom panel
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 <div class="msg" ng-hide="msg_div">
        <a ng-click="msg_div = true"></a>
    some content
</div>

 <div class="body" ng-show="msg_div">
      <a ng-click="msg_div = false"></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call a function in your template instead of setting the variable, so you have more control:

```
 <a ng-click="msg_div_click()"></a>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.msg_div_click = function(){
 $scope.msg_div = true;
 $scope.body_div = false;
}
```

Comment: This is trivial task, and you managed to over-engineer it ;)
It's simple toggle - one on, other off therefore single variable is sufficient